# how to disable radio button dynamically in angularjs using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have developing some code in Angular JS and i need to disable radio button based on previous selection or change in text box

in JS controller:

```
PPCO.cusGender = [ {
id : '1',
key : 'Male',
value : 'Male',
disable:false

}, {
id : '2',
key : 'Female',
value : 'Female',
disable:false
}, {
id : '3',
key : 'TG',
value : 'TG',
disable:false
}];

PPCO.changeapplicant = function() {
switch (PPCO.p_SALUTATION.toLowerCase().trim()) {

case 'mrs.':
case 'miss.':angular.forEach(PPCO.cusGender, function(val, key) {
if(val.key != 'Male')
{
val.disable = false;
}
});
break;
}

};
```

in HTML:

```
   <input type="text" ng-model="PPCO.changeapplicant" class="color" ng-change="PPCO.changeapplicant()">

<label class="radio" ng-repeat="option in PPCO.cusGender">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"
           ng-model="PPCO.cusgendername" value="{{option.value}}" 
           ng-disabled="option.disable">
    <i></i>
    
</label>
```

My question is i able change the "ng-disabled =true" value but it is not enabling again. How to make that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this plnkr for this case: https://plnkr.co/edit/F4JZcf6Nm5Csbxbg

I think you have 2 errors happening at the same time:

1. You're iterating over one array. So, you don't need to use `angular.forEach`, you can use `array.forEach`
2. Also, most important, you're setting false when the element is `mrs.` or `miss.` and it's ok. BUT, you're not setting back to `true`. So, you will have to include one else clause like this:

```
if (['mrs.', 'miss.'].includes($scope.applicant.toLowerCase().trim())) {
  $scope.cusGender.forEach(function(element) {
    element.disable = element.key == 'Male';
  });        
} else {
  $scope.cusGender.forEach(function(element) {
    element.disable = false;
  });        
}
```

I think that would be all!